# How to install new pods without updating old existing pods in pod file?

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

Hi I want to install new pod in my existing project, and in that there are some old pod files which we are using, So I don't want to disturb them (don't want update of old pods), I want to install only the required pod. So in stack overflow I got some results. And I tried but no use is there any other way to do this ?

I tried 3 different ways but no use :

1. a. Added required pod in the pod file then in terminal, `$pod install`
2. a. Added required pod in the pod file then in terminal, `$pod install --no --repo-update`
3. a. I opened podfile.lock in textfield. I checked my old pod versions.
   b. Modified pod file pods as
   Old Pod => `pod ‘AFNetworking’, ‘~> 3.0’`   to `pod ‘AFNetworking’, ‘3.0.0’`
   c. Added new pod then did `$pod install` or `$pod install --no --repo-update` in terminal.

So please help me how to do this ?